# Cosmology: Covariance between Gaussian distributions for complex spherical harmonics coeficients

Tags: cosmology, complex-numbers, spherical-harmonics

In the context of the computation of a variance about $a_{\ell m}$ spherical coefficients of Legendre, I am faced to an issue :

There is a term $\langle \text{Re}(a)\text{Im}(a)\rangle$ that appears where we take the notations: $$a = a_{\ell m} = \text{Re}(a) + i\,\text{Im}(a).$$

where $\text{Re}(a)$ and $\text{Im}(a)$ follow a gaussian distribution of zero mean and variance equal to $\dfrac{C_\ell}{2}$. Then, we have also $$<|a|^2> = <\text{Re}(a)^2> + <\text{Im}(a)^2> = \dfrac{C_\ell}{2} + \dfrac{C_\ell}{2} = C_\ell.$$

I don't know how to handle this term $\langle \text{Re}(a)\text{Im}(a)\rangle$ : are Re(a) and Im(a) independant or not correlated in a context of cosmology ?

If there are correlated, I can't conclude about this covariance term since I have no informations about the coefficient of correlation.

Can I assimilate $\text{Re}(a)=\text{Im}(a)$ ? I have been told that in cosmology, as general, we consider $\text{Re}(a)$ and $\text{Im}(a)$ as independant, making then to get :

$\langle \text{Re}(a)\text{Im}(a)\rangle = 0$

Could anyone tell me more about this issue ?